# How to switch between images on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I`m working on a gallery. On click the modal open pops up, and within it I want to make it possible to switch between images with the "Left" and "Right" buttons.
There is a gallery, which renders an array of imageg with map method:

```
<div className="inner-section">
   <Fade bottom>
      {
      photos.map(item => 
      <GalleryPhoto 
         key = {item.id}
         imgSrc = {item.photo}
         photoId = {item.id}
         />
      )}
   </Fade>
   <ModalImage />
</div>
```

and here is how the data file with images look:

```
const photos = [{
        photo: "./images/img_title.jpg",
        id: 1,
        caption: "",
    },
    {
        photo: "./images/img_title2.jpg",
        id: 2,
        caption: "",
    }
];
```

This is the main image component. I pass a function or opening modal window with a data of image source and image id. This function simply sets the state with modalOpen: false to true, and also inserts data about image src into the imageSRC state.

```
export default class GalleryPhoto extends Component {
  render() {
    const { imgSrc, photoId } = this.props;
    return (
      <ProductConsumer>
        {value => {
          const { handleModal } = value;
          return (
            <div className="gallery-image">
              <img
                onClick={() => handleModal(photoId, imgSrc)}
                src={imgSrc}
                alt=""
              />
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </ProductConsumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Ad here is the function:

```
handleModal = (id, photo) => {
  this.setState(
    {
      modalOpen: !this.state.modalOpen,
      imageSRC: photo
    },
    console.log(id, this.state.imageSRC)
  );
};
```

This opens the modal window on click on the photo. Here is its component:

```
<div className={"modal-container " + (modalOpen ? "visible" : "")}>
  <button className="btn move-btn">Left</button>
  <div className="modal-image-container">
    <img src={imageSRC} alt="" />
  </div>
  <button className="btn modal-close-btn" onClick={handleModal}>
    Close
  </button>
  <button className="btn move-btn">Right</button>
</div>;
```

Now I want the Left and Right buttons to switch between pictures. Does anyone know how to do it?